# Using spatial clustering or statistical tools for attribute data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics

I have a data-set of well test results with attributes like iron and manganese concentrations. What are the best tools to try and determine if there are any spatial trends for each attribute? I would like to know if there is a statistical trend and be able to display it if any trends exist. I've tried natural neighbors but that only tests the well location, I've also looked at Grouping Analysis but am unsure on how to select the proper number of groups.

Comment: you should map each well's attribute separately and look for spatial trends. If you dont want point features mapped you could create a tessellation and spatially join the attributes using a sum join to see which areas have the most of each

Comment: Thanks. I have symbolized each attribute separately and don't visually see any trends.